# VBA error code : "For control variable already in use" for combination execution

Tags: excel, vba, combinations, multiple-columns

Thank you so much @ chris neilsen, Siddharth Rout, FunThomas, user10186832 for making me realize how to put out question.
Yes, I am preety naive to VBA in excel. I apologies for the mistake.
I am trying to do following:

[image]

Where, B2:B13 is points and C2:C13 is number of repeats. I want to have pattern as given F, J an N columns.
I made the code based on the web surfing and try to do the same.
Im getting an error message saying control variable already in use. When the error pops up the second **Sub combinations()** is highlighted in the VBA editor. I trying to get combinations in different columns and eliminating the rows which has blank cell in column. Hope I am able to explain. Can anyone help correcting this code. Thank you

```
Sub combinations()
i = 1
For Each cella In Sheet3.Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each cellb In Sheet3.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("D:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                    For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("F:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                        For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                            For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                                For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("I:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                                    For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("J:J").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                                        For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("K:K").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                                            For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("L:L").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                                                For Each cellc In Sheet3.Range("M:M").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                                                    Sheet9.Range("A" & i).Value = cella.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("B" & i).Value = cellb.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("C" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("D" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("E" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("F" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("G" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("H" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("I" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("J" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("K" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("L" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    Sheet9.Range("M" & i).Value = cellc.Value
                                                    i = i + 1
                                                Next
                                            Next
                                        Next
                                    Next
                                Next
                            Next
                        Next
                    Next
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next

Set mysheet1 = Sheet9
    row1 = mysheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For i = row1 To 1 Step -1
    If Len(mysheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 0 Then
      mysheet1.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Comment: The Error message tells you the issue: you're reusing `cellc` in many nested `for` loops.  You can't do that

Comment: **1.** Also the next error that you may get is with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)`. Always use proper error handling when working with `SpecialCells`
**2.** Also could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? I feel like there may be a better way to achieve what you want...

Comment: Just be aware: If you have only 3 values per column, this will give you 3^13 rows, that's 1.5m - more than Excel can handle. But you will get a runtime error much earlier if you don't declare `i` explicitly as `Long`, because without declaration VBA will implicitly declare it as Integer which has a limit of 32'768. That said: You might think about a recursive algorithm instead of 13 nested loops.

Comment: Welcome SP160477! Please take some time to read the introduction to Stack Overflow and earn your next badge. https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Range(A:A) is 1048576 cells long, so the loop may take longer than you expect to execute.

Comment: @user10186832: Only if filled - `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)` will return only cells with values

Comment: @FunThomas OK that is something I have learned today then! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.specialcells

Comment: and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlcelltype

Comment: there's more ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-constants

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could shorten up your loop to delete lines with one line of code:

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheet9.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

This deletes every line where cell A is empty. The suppressed error handling is needed because if there is no empty cell in column A an error would occur.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with that horrible nested for-loops. But the others told you already in the comments that this might fail. At least you have to name the loop variables unique, but I doubt that this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all apologies and I finally I was able to do that using following code with data in AI108:AU119 in sheet name Input_plan:

```
    Sub combinations()
    Dim columnnonBlanks As Long, rownonBlanks As Long, i As Long, k As Long
    Dim Cell As Range, Rng As Range
    Dim j As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer, p As Integer
                
    rownonBlanks = 0
    columnnonBlanks = 0
    k = 0
         
    Sheets("Input_plan").Select
    For Each Cell In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, 35), Cells(108, 47))
        If Cell <> "" Then rownonBlanks = rownonBlanks + 1
    Next Cell
    
    rownonBlanks = rownonBlanks + 34
    
    For Each Cell In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, rownonBlanks), Cells(119, rownonBlanks))
        If Cell <> "" Then columnnonBlanks = columnnonBlanks + 1
    Next Cell
    columnnonBlanks = columnnonBlanks + 107
   
    i = 178
    
    For Each Cella In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, 35), Cells(columnnonBlanks, 35)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        For Each Cellb In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, 36), Cells(columnnonBlanks, 36)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
            If IsEmpty(Range("C108").Value) = True Then
            For Each Cellc In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, 37), Cells(columnnonBlanks, 37)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                If IsEmpty(Range("D108").Value) = True Then
                For Each Celld In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, 38), Cells(columnnonBlanks, 38)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                    If IsEmpty(Range("E108").Value) = True Then
                    For Each Celle In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, 39), Cells(columnnonBlanks, 39)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                        If IsEmpty(Range("F108").Value) = True Then
                        For Each Cellf In Sheet2.Range(Cells(108, 40), Cells(columnnonBlanks, 40)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
                        Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value = Cella.Value
                        Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value = Cellb.Value
                        Sheet2.Range("E" & i).Value = Cellc.Value
                        Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Value = Celld.Value
                        Sheet2.Range("G" & i).Value = Celle.Value
                        Sheet2.Range("H" & i).Value = Cellf.Value
                        i = i + 1
                        Next
                    Else
                    Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value = Cella.Value
                    Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value = Cellb.Value
                    Sheet2.Range("E" & i).Value = Cellc.Value
                    Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Value = Celld.Value
                    Sheet2.Range("G" & i).Value = Celle.Value
                    i = i + 1
                    End If
                    Next
                Else
                Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value = Cella.Value
                Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value = Cellb.Value
                Sheet2.Range("E" & i).Value = Cellc.Value
                Sheet2.Range("F" & i).Value = Celld.Value
                i = i + 1
                End If
                Next
            Else
            Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value = Cella.Value
            Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value = Cellb.Value
            Sheet2.Range("E" & i).Value = Cellc.Value
            i = i + 1
            End If
            Next
        Else
        Sheet2.Range("C" & i).Value = Cella.Value
        Sheet2.Range("D" & i).Value = Cellb.Value
        i = i + 1
        End If
        Next
    Next

    ActiveSheet.Range("C274").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(MATCH(""zzzz"",R[-96]C:R[-1]C),"""")"
    Range("C274").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D274:H274").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("B274").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[1]:RC[6])"
    Range("B275").Select

Sheets("Input_plan").Select
j = Range("B274")
j = j + 177


For Each Cell In Range(Cells(178, 3), Cells(178, 8))
       If Cell <> "" Then k = k + 1
Next Cell

k = k + 2


'Selecting all data
Set Rng = Range(Cells(178, 3), Cells(j, k))

'Selecting Blank cells
Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select

'Deleting complete row
With ActiveSheet
Intersect(Selection.EntireRow, .Columns(1)).EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```

Please apologies for any mistakes made in the code.

Comment: Please anybody help me to give the proper subject heading for this question.